# How to increase size of canvas to 1080*1920 from 400*400 in code.org gamelab?

Tags: javascript, html, css, p5.js, code.org

I am Manav. I read articles, tried coding and researched a lot but I didn't know how to increase canvas size in code.org gamelab. Many suggested me to do code on editor.p5js, but there I am facing a lot of problems that I am not in code.org, My previous apps looked bad in the 400*400 canvas. I know that we can increase the size by dragging the canvas but it doesn't make muck of a change. After a lot of research I joined this community which was recommended by many people. I hope my issue get solved here.

Link to code.org :

https://code.org/

I tried using

createCanvas(1080,1920);

And

resizeCanvas(1090,1920);

But both don't work

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add some code to the question and show us what you have tried. Explain what is going wrong with the code and we will be glad to help.

Comment: I tried using:-.   createCanvas(1080, 1920);

Comment: And  resizeCanvas (1080,1920);

Comment: But both didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase canvas side in code.org default is 400x 400

Comment: Ok got it. Anyways I have left programming in code.org. BTW thanks for replying ☺

Answer (score 0):

You can't increase the canvas size for a project but you can increase it for your convenience by dragging the grey line near and right the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can, but it has to be exported first:

Go to `p5.play.js` then find :

```
 this._defaultCanvasSize = {
    width: 400,
    height: 400
  };
```

I do this when making games for `itch.io` or whatever. It helps a lot well there is a downside to this:
It is impossible to do it without exporting. The width and height can be different changes and may mess up your game sometimes.